# 2012 iMac: Stalling on boot (macOS Mojave 10.14.5) External SSD. Display Issue?

Tags: imac, hardware, crash, logs

Adding more detail:
This is late 2012 iMac (13,2) with 128GB original internal NVMe but with new Samsung EVO 860 1TB SSD. I used to be able to talk to it via target disk mode (where I erased drives) but no longer can access vis TDM. I now have tried both 10.13.6 and 10.14.5 ext SSD to boot (or recovery) (or install), every thing hangs on UI process startup. Hope EFI Rom mismatch rather than real hw error. Ran h.Sierra w/ new hw before Mojave upgrade killed it.
Maybe a downgrade from 283.0.0.0.0 EFI Firmware could help but people have said impossible to downgrade.
I can only get to Single User Mode - anything else involves UI Process start then hang in Windows Server - wondering if to do with Ambient Light Sensor - maybe I botched cable hookup.

Here is log:

```
10:26:32.416886 -0700   Installer Progress  Progress UI App Starting
10:26:32.596156 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system) Service "com.apple.ManagedClient.startup" tried to register for endpoint "com.apple.ManagedClient.agent" already registered by owner: com.apple.ManagedClient
10:26:32.710204 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:32.941178 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:34.382271 -0700   logd    _logd_remote_start_service: listener activated for com.apple.logd.remote-daemon
10:26:35.031124 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:35.995553 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.202) com.apple.pluginkit.pkd (lint): Service sets EnableTransactions=false and EnablePressuredExit=true, which makes no sense. Enabling Transactions.
10:26:36.541964 -0700   launchd BUG in libdispatch client: mach_recv, monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked { 0x7f8a5304f400[source], ident: 161799 / 0x27807, handler: 0x106c7540e }
10:26:36.818377 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:36.995037 -0700   syspolicyd  objc[182]: Class AKELData is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy (0x1095a3ef0) and /usr/libexec/syspolicyd (0x1087a3c40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:36.995162 -0700   syspolicyd  objc[182]: Class SPExecutionHistoryItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy (0x1095a3e50) and /usr/libexec/syspolicyd (0x1087a4000). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:37.731805 -0700   systemstats DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:26:37.863976 -0700   mds objc[63]: Class MDSObjectToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightServerKit.framework/Versions/A/SpotlightServerKit (0x10a811de0) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds (0x10a5c8f40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:37.864163 -0700   mds objc[63]: Class MDSToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightServerKit.framework/Versions/A/SpotlightServerKit (0x10a811d90) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds (0x10a5c9490). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:37.864287 -0700   mds objc[63]: Class MDSReadCopyUpdate is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightServerKit.framework/Versions/A/SpotlightServerKit (0x10a811e30) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds (0x10a5ca020). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:37.864496 -0700   mds objc[63]: Class MDSInternalToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpotlightServerKit.framework/Versions/A/SpotlightServerKit (0x10a811d40) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds (0x10a5cb100). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10:26:38.271670 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.89) com.apple.pluginkit.pkd (lint): Service sets EnableTransactions=false and EnablePressuredExit=true, which makes no sense. Enabling Transactions.
10:26:38.452634 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:47.021256 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.dpd[179]) Service exited with abnormal code: 75
10:26:48.382117 -0700   airportd    DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:26:49.321153 -0700   WindowServer    DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:26:49.419191 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.88) com.apple.pluginkit.pkd (lint): Service sets EnableTransactions=false and EnablePressuredExit=true, which makes no sense. Enabling Transactions.
10:26:52.138252 -0700   nsurlsessiond   DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:26:52.143428 -0700   xpcproxy    libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
10:26:52.111251 -0700   timed   settimeofday({0x5ceacc5c,0x19be9}) == 0
10:26:53.483321 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer[117]) Service exited due to SIGABRT
10:26:53.548115 -0700   WindowServer    DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:26:53.586312 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent) Service only ran for 4 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 6 seconds.
10:26:53.678423 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer[211]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
10:26:53.678478 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
10:26:57.021957 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.dpd[206]) Service exited with abnormal code: 75
10:27:03.742655 -0700   WindowServer    DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:27:03.778320 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent) Service only ran for 4 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 6 seconds.
10:27:03.870368 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer[216]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
10:27:03.870439 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
10:27:07.809317 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.dpd[214]) Service exited with abnormal code: 75
10:27:13.934911 -0700   WindowServer    DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
10:27:13.970915 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent) Service only ran for 4 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 6 seconds.
10:27:14.062886 -0700   com.apple.xpc.launchd   (com.apple.WindowServer[219]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

and from WindowServer Crash log:

```
Process:               WindowServer [183]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               600.00 (340.26)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           WindowServer [183]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2019-05-26 10:20:41.827 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        04ADE721-5882-9162-4D00-6F4A60D95324


Time Awake Since Boot: 54 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Assertion failed: (false - Driver Error: FB: 0 of 3 opened, succeeded 0 times, failed 1 times; WS: 1st PID 183, is not on installer
AppleIntelFramebuffer = 0
IOFramebufferUserClient = 0
LER:
LER:
LER:
), function CGXMappedDisplayStart, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreDisplay/CoreDisplay-109.19/CoreDisplay/IODisplay/MappedDisplay.cpp, line 5030.


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead62c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb30bf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010e8ff6a6 abort + 127
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010e8c820d __assert_rtn + 324
4   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c7f6184 0x10c7eb000 + 45444
5   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c86ad33 0x10c7eb000 + 523571
6   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c894489 CGXDisplayDriverInitialize + 934
7   com.apple.SkyLight              0x000000010b7a058f WSInitialize + 3065
8   com.apple.SkyLight              0x000000010b83b4ea SLXServer + 1338
9   WindowServer                    0x000000010b5db50d 0x10b5da000 + 5389
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000010e7fc3d5 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.VirtualDisplayListener
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead022a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead076c mach_msg + 60
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead785c mach_msg_server_once + 284
3   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c7f3630 0x10c7eb000 + 34352
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010e7775f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010e77863d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010e77e8e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010e77f396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010e7876ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d3fd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead022a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010ead076c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c80d48f 0x10c7eb000 + 140431
3   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c89fc6d 0x10c7eb000 + 740461
4   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x000000010c89fd0f 0x10c7eb000 + 740623
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2e2eb _pthread_body + 126
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb31249 _pthread_start + 66
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d40d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010eb2d3f0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000001141445c0  rcx: 0x00007ffee4623f38  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee4623f70  rsp: 0x00007ffee4623f38
   r8: 0x00000000000013a6   r9: 0xcccccccccccccccd  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x000000010c7e1000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x000000000000002d
  rip: 0x000000010ead62c6  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x000000010eb302dc

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10b5da000 -        0x10b5dbfff  WindowServer (600.00 - 340.26) <ECD57D28-FB28-3D90-A231-9B4F085C8B8D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Resources/WindowServer
       0x10b5e5000 -        0x10b893ffb  com.apple.SkyLight (1.600.0 - 340.26) <CD2A7069-6CEA-3737-9E9D-7AE2FED912AB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight
       0x10b97e000 -        0x10b97fffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.250.1) <1A13E822-B59C-3A36-A2E4-9968149714F9> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
       0x10b985000 -        0x10b986ff7  com.apple.AggregateDictionary (1.0 - 1) <A6AF8AC4-1F25-37C4-9157-A02E9C200926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/Versions/A/AggregateDictionary
```

Comment: Maybe I have not connected display correctly when putting Mac back together?
Mention of WindowServer and AmbientLight sensor?

Comment: You will need to add that info to the original question along with any other changes you have made recently. Also need the model of Mac you have. Bet detailed and even overly complete. More info is better info, without it we are stuck with only what you write and that is often not enough.

Comment: I tried to put that in the original question and it complained that it thought it was spam. Sorry I'm a newbie here so don't know how to avoid my the spam filter. This is late 2012 iMac with 128GB original internal NVMe but with new Samsung EVO 860 1TB SSD. I used to be able to talk to it via target disk mode (where I erased drives) but no longer can access vis TDM. I now have tried both 10.13.6 and 10.14.5 ext SSD to boot (or recovery) (or install), every thing hangs on UI process startup. Hope EFI Rom mismatch rather than real hw error. Ran h.Sierra w/ new hw before Mojave upgrade killed it

Comment: Update from today. Internal drives work - but can't see with my macbook Air. No new  ROM available. Can't downgrade. Shop thinks logic board failure :( See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/361035/333467